# Facebook Like button broken on Wordpress homepage

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

The Facebook Like button on my Wordpress site's homepage doesn't work.

When clicked, rather than pull in homepage data, it pulls in data of the most recent post.

I have not changed any code, but the relevant meta tags in my site header are:

```html
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="<?php bloginfo('name') ?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1734267835" />
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the homepage url in wp is

```
<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>
```

so, change

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" />
```

by

```
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>" />
```